# Generate multiple output from the sql query using chef inspec

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, chef-infra, devops

I am executing the below sql code in sqlcmd to get two outputs "value configured" and "value in use" :

```
SELECT name,
CAST(value as int) as value_configured,
CAST(value_in_use as int) as value_in_use
FROM sys.configurations
WHERE name = ‘xp_cmdshell’;
```

So far below code generates only one output, How do convert the code in chef inspec to generate two outputs:

```
 describe sql.query("SELECT name,
CAST(value as int) as value_configured,
CAST(value_in_use as int) as value_in_use
FROM sys.configurations
WHERE name = ‘xp_cmdshell’").row(0).column('value_configured')do
its("value") { should eq '0' }
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that:

```rb
# Save the query result into a variable
result = sql.query("SELECT name,
  CAST(value as int) as value_configured,
  CAST(value_in_use as int) as value_in_use
  FROM sys.configurations
  WHERE name = ‘xp_cmdshell’").row(0)

# take 1 column
describe result.column('value_configured') do
  its("value") { should eq 0 }
end

# take another column
describe result.column('value_in_use') do
  its("value") { should eq 0 }
end
```

Comment: Hi Draco , is it possible to generate the value_configured and value_in_use using one syntax than two separate syntax.

Comment: I don't think so.